# jQuery range input default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, range

Expected to `$('input[type=range]').val()` return empty value (If `value=''`).

But, jQuery the return `50%` of the `(min+max)` of the range input element.

[image: Default value of range slider.]

https://jsfiddle.net/maheshwaghmare/f33Ljjty/

---

Any solutoin to detect `empty` value of `input[type=range]` element though jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Input type range `Default` return value is the range of the number ,not value of attribute .if you need ah value `attr` .try with [`attr('value')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizru_FxaHUAhUYSo8KHdK0BuIQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg&sig2=W0n_s9LYMIp6b1LEm7k_8w)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
if(!$('.one').attr('value').trim() || !$('.two').attr('value').trim()){ // validate the attribute value
console.log('any one range attr value is empty')
}
 var rangeOne = 'Defult One: ' + $('.one').val() + '<br/>';
  var rangeTwo = 'Defult Two: ' + $('.two').val() + '<br/>';
 $('.result').html( rangeOne + rangeTwo );
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 5px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Range One <input class="one" min="768" step="1" max="1920" type="range" value=""> (min='768' step='1' max='1920' value='')<br/>
Range Two <input class="two" min="768" step="1" max="1920" type="range" value="800"> (min='768' step='1' max='1920' value='800')

<br/><br/><br/>
<span class="result"></span>
```